# Sync Android with iTunes

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music

I have iTunes on my Windows 7 PC. I love how flawlessly iPhones sync with iTunes, but I have an Android phone :( Is there an easy way to plug in my Android and sync it with iTunes?

If it matters I have an HTC First.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the  [iTunes to android Sync-Windows](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mahmed.net.synctuneswirelessfree&hl=en)
 on your your computer.

Description

Requires: iTunes+Windows not for mac users
Synctunes wireless syncs an iTunes libray from Windows to android.

It allows you to sync your iTunes music, podcasts and videos from your iTunes library on windows to to your android device over WiFi.

Features:

From iTunes computer it Syncs to android like below

Syncs to internal or external SDCARD

Syncs Podcasts from your iTunes library to android.

Syncs Music tracks from iTunes to android.

Syncs Playlists.

Syncs tracks from iTunes store downloaded on your computer

Syncs album art

Organizes songs in android by artist/albums

You can filter your tracks to be synced (by size, length , date etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [iSyncr](http://www.jrtstudio.com/iSyncr-iTunes-for-Android). I was regretting having all of my music in iTunes until I found it, but now syncs are painless. I'm Mac, but the app is completely cross-platform. It's got my vote, FWIW.